# N groups have a list of numbers that it can pick. Determine if all groups will be able to choose a number if one group chooses number i

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, match, bipartite

Say that there is a group, each with numbers that it can pick.

```
Group 1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 
Group 2: [2, 3, 4], 
Group 3: [2, 3, 4], 
Group 4: [4]
```

Say that it initially Group 4 chooses 4 in its list. Now, other groups can't use a 4. One possible arrangement is group 1 chooses the 1, group 3 chooses the 2, and group 2 chooses the 3. However, if group 1 initially chooses 4, there is no valid arrangement, since the only number group 4 can use is 4. Since 4 was used by group 1, group 4 can't choose any numbers, and thus not every group can choose a number. Return true or false if given that group N chooses a number i that they can pick, all the rest of the groups can choose a number. Is there an efficient O(n) or O(n^2) algorithm?

My solution attempt/thoughts:

Originally, I thought that maybe converting this into a directed graph representation and determining if there is a way for all nodes to be traversed to from another node. However, this would mean there are loops involved, and also this is polynomial.

Comment: Useful keywords: you are looking for a "marriage" (or "matching") in a "bipartite graph".

Comment: Question - How can this be a bipartite graph? Would you have to make edges undirected?

Comment: On the left side you have nodes Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4 and on the right side you have nodes 1, 2, 3, 4. There are edges left-right, but no edges left-left nor right-right. That's the definition of a bipartite graph. Yes, edges are undirected.

Comment: In python with networkx: `d = {'g1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'g2': [2, 3, 4], 'g3': [2, 3, 4], 'g4': [4]}; G = nx.Graph(); g.add_nodes_from(d.keys(), bipartite=0); g.add_nodes_from((n for v in d.values() for n in v), bipartite=1); g.add_edges_from((k,n) for k,v in d.items() for n in v)` Now `g.edges` is `[('g1', 1), ('g1', 2), ('g1', 3), ('g1', 4), ('g2', 2), ('g2', 3), ('g2', 4), ('g3', 2), ('g3', 3), ('g3', 4), ('g4', 4)]`; Then `nx.bipartite.matching.hopcroft_karp_matching(g, d.keys())` returns `{'g3': 2, 'g4': 4, 'g1': 1, 'g2': 3, 1: 'g1', 2: 'g3', 3: 'g2', 4: 'g4'}`