# Most optimal algorithm to pick things from a list/pool?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, greedy

I have a list of fruits `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Grape']`

Person A wants to take Apple and Banana

Person B wants to take Apple and Banana and Orange

Person C wants to take Orange and Grape

If a fruit you want is taken, you cannot pick take any fruits at all. For example, the possible solutions for this are:

1. Person A and Person C takes all the fruits (most optimal)
2. Person B takes Apple, Banana, Orange

The goal is to take the most number of fruits (solution 1), is there an algorithm for figuring that out without trying all the combinations?

Comment: You're looking for a **marriage** (or **matching**) in a **bipartite graph**. See for instance: [Wikipedia: Bipartite graph #matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Matching)

Comment: Someone else asked pretty much the same question yesterday. Perhaps they're your classmate? [N groups have a list of numbers that it can pick. Determine if all groups will be able to choose a number if one group chooses number i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296930/n-groups-have-a-list-of-numbers-that-it-can-pick-determine-if-all-groups-will-b#comment126028414_71296930)